# How can I prevent a duplicate external request?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I builded a rest API that can let an external service to call it in Salesforce, the third server will re-send a same request if the API can not response a result in 3s that will create some duplicate records when the same request send again.

So how can I prevent to execute the logic again when a transaction is handing the request.

Comment: Check duplicate record based on some field and throw error.

Comment: The current transaction does not end, so that can not get the record in the duplicate request.

Comment: This is the reason you need a unique reference or externalID. Ask the third part to send an unique field.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not control third part.